# Can we use cached RDD across batches on an executor

Tags: caching, apache-spark, streaming, rdd, executor

I have a case where I want to download some data from a remote store every one hour and store that as Key-Value pairs in a RDD on an executor/worker. I want to cache this RDD so that all future jobs/tasks/batches running on this executor/worker can use the cached RDD to do a lookup. Is this possible in Spark Streaming?

Some relevant code or pointers to relevant code will be helpful.

Comment: 1. What happens to older data? 2. When you say "across batches", do you mean other spark applications? Or within the same application? 3. Is it always append or upsert?

Comment: 1. Old data should remain and new data should get added/appended. 2. "across bacthes" of same spark application. 3. It will be always append

Answer (score 3):

Alluxio is a memory-centric distributed storage system. Alluxio can be used to cache Spark RDDs in memory, for multiple and future Spark applications and jobs to access.

[Spark can store RDDs in Alluxio memory](http://www.alluxio.com/2016/08/effective-spark-rdds-with-alluxio/), and future Spark jobs can read them from Alluxio memory. That blog post has more details on how that works. Here is information on [how to setup and configure Alluxio with Spark](http://www.alluxio.org/docs/master/en/Running-Spark-on-Alluxio.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a giant, distributed `map`, and you want to use Spark, write a standalone job that downloads the data every hours, and caches the `RDD` thus obtained (you can unpersist the old `RDD`). Let us call this Job `DataRefresher`.

You can then expose a REST api (if you are on `Scala`, consider using `Scalatra`) that wraps the `DataRefresher`, and returns the value, given the key. Something like: `http://localhost:9191/lookup/key`, which can be used by other jobs to do a relatively fast lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements, here is what I would propose:

1. Run a Spark Application job every 1 hour, which will get the data from external data source and append to a hive table.
2. Use Spark thrift server to access the data

Note: Your notion of "caching within executor to use across application" is not correct. Executors relates to single Spark App, so as any RDD within that app.

If you really need to invest on caching data on distributed nodes, you may want to consider off-heap in-memory databases, such as Tachyon and Alluxio

Comment: I want to use this as a local cache lookup. I want to "cache within executor for the same/single application" so that all jobs of this single application can reuse and/or reuse the cache.